# MySQL SELECT statement with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have an interesting SQL query.

I have two tables; called “DATA” and “DICT”.

The DATA table contains column headings.

The DICT table contains (as data in rows) the column headings of the DATA table.

IOW:

DATA has column headings:

- Code
- Description
- DR
- CR

DICT has rows for

- Code
- Description

Using the MySQL SELECT statement I can:

```
SELECT column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE (table_name = "DATA");
```

That returns the column names.

Now what I wish to achieve is a SELECT statement (with the necessary JOIN) to return the rows which ARE EXCLUDED in the DICT table (as rows).

So, per example:

I require an appropriate SELECT statement to return JUST the fact that
DR and CR are NOT rows in the DICT table.

Believe me, I’ve tried many logical combinations and it appears that I may have a problem due to the “WHERE (table_name = "DATA")” part.

Thanks

Comment: Show an example of the output you expect, and some sample data from your two tables. In your question, you show something from the two tables, but it isn't clear if they are column names or data values. Please clarify

Comment: DATA: Only interested in cols (column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE (table_name = “DATA”)
DICT has ROWS entry for SOME of the cols in DATA.
Example:
STRUCTURE OF DATA is: 
SELECT column_name from information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE (table_name = "DATA");
Code
Description
DR
CR
4 rows in set
ROWS in DICT are:
Code
Description
DR
3 rows in set
Statement should return only CR

Comment: Please add info by editing your question, rather than in a comment.

Comment: A schema isn't a select statement. It's a list of the column names and their types/sizes.

Answer (score 0):

As Sloan Thrasher said, an example would be helpful.  That said, is this what you're after?

```
SELECT DISTINCT is1.column_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS is1
LEFT JOIN DICT ON is1.table_schema = 'YourSchema' AND is1.table_name = "DATA" AND is1.column_name = DICT.column_name
WHERE DICT.column_name IS NULL
;
```

Comment: I will use Python lists to provide a result. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name, dict.Item from information_schema.COLUMNS LEFT JOIN dict ON dict.Item = column_name WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'Data') and (dict.Item IS NULL);